# bash monitoring file with tail including ability to switch file dynamically?

Tags: bash, shell, tail

I have a script that monitors a log file line by line and pushes values retrieved elsewhere (eg to a graph app). However the log file name and/or **path** may change around midnight, eg due to **app** log rotation (not unix log rotation) and the App's EOD procedure. 
For example a log file under `/path/to/log/20191018/log.txt` could switch to `/path/to/log/20191019/log.txt`

What would be the best approach to handle such case in the script ? e.g. to make tail command to start following a new file ?

```
tail -f "$file" | while read line
do case "$line" in
        *"a_string"*) do_something 
         ;;
        ...
        ...
    esac
done
```

Comment: The solution most probably is `tail -F`

Comment: @Kamil thanks I think this would solve the name change, but what about a change of path? E.g. when the original file/path remains but new logs start getting written into a different file with same basename but under a different dir ?

Comment: `getting written into a different file with same basename but under a different dir` - then, how do you detect that? How do you know which file name and in what dir the log file is in? Why would any software change the path to the log files while running?

Comment: The log file path has a dir mid-way named after the current date in YYYYMMDD. For example `/path/to/log/20191018/log.txt` . This date corresponds to the App's system date, hence it would change after its EOD procedure and then start logging to `/path/to/log/20191019/log.txt`

Comment: This is completely different explanation as to what you described. Please edit your post and include such information. So, `inotifywait` on `/path/to/log` for new directories, and every time a new dir is created, switch to new log file.

Comment: @Kamil I did mention "the log file/**path** may change..", I don't think it's relevant at all to mention _why_ it changes. I will add the dir switch example. Thanks for your suggestion however - will try to see how `inotifywait` could work

Comment: This is part of why traditional UNIX log rotation systems always write to the same file, and then just *rotate* to distinct datestamped names after-the-fact -- that way `tail -F` does the right thing, because the most-recent file's name is constant.

Comment: @Charles agreed, but in this case unfortunately it's the app itself that is "rotating" the log file, in a totally awkward way...

Comment: Could you `tail` a symlink and update the symlink's destination when you notice?

Comment: @tripleee apparently `tail -F` doesn't work on symlinks. I think it's related to [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2011-08/msg00041.html) . I also tried with `tail -F "$(readlink -e mylink)"` but still doesn't work, tail follows the original symlink for some reason, even after I modify it from another session...

Comment: Of course the `readlink` only gets evaluated before you run `tail`; it just sees the resolved absolute name.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that your script, as it stands, has no way to know that the log rotation has happened. You *could* wrap your log parser in a child process and have the parent monitor the directories for new files, but that requires some assumptions, as well as some complicated process/file monitoring logic.

I generally prefer "notification" mechanisms over "polling" mechanisms, so a clean solution to this problem would be to have the log rotation mechanism restart your script when the file changes. If you are using `logrotate` and are allowed to modify its configuration, then this can be done by simply adding a `postrotate` entry to the appropriate configuration file:

```
/path/to/monitored/directory {
    ...
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall myscript
        /path/to/myscript
    endscript
}
```